# Spark Scala: Cannot up cast from string to int as it may truncate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got this exception while playing with spark.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Cannot up cast `price` from string to int as it may truncate
>       The type path of the target object is:
>       - field (class: "scala.Int", name: "price")
>       - root class: "org.spark.code.executable.Main.Record"
>       You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;

How Can this exception be solved?  Here is the code

```
object Main {

 case class Record(transactionDate: Timestamp, product: String, price: Int, paymentType: String, name: String, city: String, state: String, country: String,
                accountCreated: Timestamp, lastLogin: Timestamp, latitude: String, longitude: String)
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

   System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\winutils\\");

   val schema = Encoders.product[Record].schema

   val df = SparkConfig.sparkSession.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("SalesJan2009.csv");

   import SparkConfig.sparkSession.implicits._
   val ds = df.as[Record]

  //ds.groupByKey(body => body.state).count().show()

  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed.{
  count => typedCount,
  sum => typedSum
}

  ds.groupByKey(body => body.state)
  .agg(typedSum[Record](_.price).name("sum(price)"))
  .withColumnRenamed("value", "group")
  .alias("Summary by state")
  .show()
}
```

Comment: can you try moving the case class Record outside the main, and can you post the sample data ?

Comment: @Shankar Koirala here is the link of data that I am using
https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/blob/master/test/test_files/SalesJan2009.csv

Comment: Yes I also tried moving case Class Record outside from main

Comment: @Shankar Koirala sorry now I check that this issues come converting DataFrame to DataSet[Record]. Please help in that

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You read the csv file first and tried to convert to it to dataset which has different schema. Its better to pass the schema created while reading the csv file as below

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("test")
  .getOrCreate()

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Record].schema

val ds = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)  // passing schema 
  .option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") // passing timestamp format
  .csv(path)// csv path
  .as[Record] // convert to DS
```

The default timestampFormat is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` so you also need to pass your custom timestampFormat.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any reason this wouldn't work in spark-shell? When I add my schema as you suggested, my code compiles (`:paste <file path>`) and runs (`main.main`), but all fields in all the rows come back `null`.

Comment: @combinatorist this should work on spark-shell as well.

Comment: @Shankar, so what (in general) does it mean if it runs with the schema, but every field is null? Does that mean none of the rows in the file matched my schema, or could it be something else?

Comment: Did it work with the normal class? One of the reason would be, not matching the schema for some of the fields, which loads all the columns of that row will be null.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal class". If I don't apply my schema, the dataframe populates, but everything is a string, and if I cast (`.as`) my schema on that dataframe, I get the nulls again. FWIW, this is my case class: `case class OpioidScript(prescription_key:String, member_key:String, morphine_equivalent_dose:String, prescription_fill_date:Date, days_supply:Int)`

Comment: Nice! Did not know about extracting using `Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema`

Comment: @combinatorist Possibly the schema is incorrectly defined. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193192/5986661

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was using this:

```
case class OriginalData(ORDER_ID: Int, USER_ID: Int, ORDER_NUMBER: Int, ORDER_DOW: Int, ORDER_HOUR_OF_DAY: Int, DAYS_SINCE_PRIOR_ORDER: Double, ORDER_DETAIL: String)
```

However, in the CSV file, I had this for example:

[image]

Yes, having "Friday" where only integers representing days of the week should appear, means that I need to clean data. However, to be able to read my CSV file using `spark.read.csv("data/jaimemontoya/01.csv")`, I used the following code, where the value of `ORDER_DOW` now is `String`, not `Int` anymore:

```
case class OriginalData(ORDER_ID: Int, USER_ID: Int, ORDER_NUMBER: Int, ORDER_DOW: String, ORDER_HOUR_OF_DAY: Int, DAYS_SINCE_PRIOR_ORDER: Double, ORDER_DETAIL: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this option on read:

```
.option("inferSchema", true)
```