# Trim csv file before importing into a Spark Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I've seen this post about how to specify an schema for creating a Dataset

[Spark Scala: Cannot up cast from string to int as it may truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414718/spark-scala-cannot-up-cast-from-string-to-int-as-it-may-truncate)

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("test")
  .getOrCreate()

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Record].schema

val ds = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(schema)  // passing schema 
  .option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm") // passing timestamp format
  .csv(path)// csv path
  .as[Record] // convert to DS
```

It works for me, but not when there are withispaces in the csv. Is it possible to trim the csv in this same spark.read sequence?

Comment: I think you have `ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` and `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace` options with Spark 2.2

Comment: i think these two options are not yet merged PR #306: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/pull/306, it exist another option to delete the malformed lines  .mode("DROPMALFORMED") if you have a few lines malformed