# Cannot up cast `ordId` from string to int as it may truncate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to read a small file as a Dataset but its giving the  error

> "Cannot up cast `ordId` from string to int as it may truncate".

Here is the code:

```
object Main {
  case class Orders(ordId: Int, custId: Int, amount: Float, date: String)

  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit ={

    val schema = Encoders.product[Orders].schema

      val spark = SparkSession.builder
        .master ("local[*]")
        .appName ("")
        .getOrCreate ()


    val df = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("/mnt/data/orders.txt")


    import spark.implicits._
    val ds = df.as[Orders]

  }
}
```

orders.txt

```
ordId,custId,amount,date
1234,123,400,20190112
2345,456,600,20190122
1345,123,500,20190123
3456,345,800,20190202
5678,123,600,20190203
6578,455,900,20190301
```

How can I resolve this error?. Also I would like to know that do I first need to read the file as a Dataframe and then convert to a Dataset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Scala: Cannot up cast from string to int as it may truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414718/spark-scala-cannot-up-cast-from-string-to-int-as-it-may-truncate)

Comment: @blackbishop I already went through that post but it does not answers my question. Though the question asked is similar

Comment: But you're not passing the schema when you read the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by **passing** `schema`(using `.schema`) while reading as `DataFrame`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Orders].schema
val ds=spark.read.option("header",true).schema(schema).csv("/mnt/data/orders.txt").as[Orders]
ds.show()
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+------+------+--------+
|ordId|custId|amount|    date|
+-----+------+------+--------+
| 1234|   123| 400.0|20190112|
| 2345|   456| 600.0|20190122|
| 1345|   123| 500.0|20190123|
| 3456|   345| 800.0|20190202|
| 5678|   123| 600.0|20190203|
| 6578|   455| 900.0|20190301|
+-----+------+------+--------+
```

**Schema:**

```
ds.printSchema()

root
 |-- ordId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- custId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: float (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

***Update:***

There are multiple ways to get month info extracted from date column

1. Using `unix_timestamp`,`from_unixtime` functions:

```
ds.withColumn("mnth",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"date","yyyyMMdd"),"MMM")).show()
```

**(or)**

2. Using `to_date`,`date_format` functions:

```
ds.withColumn("mnth",date_format(to_date($"date","yyyyMMdd"),"MMM")).show()
```

**Result:**

```
+-----+------+------+--------+----+
|ordId|custId|amount|    date|mnth|
+-----+------+------+--------+----+
| 1234|   123| 400.0|20190112| Jan|
| 2345|   456| 600.0|20190122| Jan|
| 1345|   123| 500.0|20190123| Jan|
| 3456|   345| 800.0|20190202| Feb|
| 5678|   123| 600.0|20190203| Feb|
| 6578|   455| 900.0|20190301| Mar|
+-----+------+------+--------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks @Shu. I missed that

Comment: this is not related to the error, but can you explain how can i have the month information(like JAN, FEB, MAR) from the date field?

Comment: @ben, Please check the `update` section of the answer!!