# Spark - ignore non existing columns for Dataset.as[SomeCaseClass]

Tags: apache-spark

Spark Dataset.as function throws exception for columns not found - `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'attr_3' given input columns: [attr_1, attr_2];`

```
case class SomeCaseClass(attr_1: String, attr_2: Long, attr_3: String)

spark.read.parquet("some_directory").as[SomeCaseClass]
```

Is there any way to avoid such exception, and put null for non existing columns?

Comment: do you have `attr_3` available in "some_directory"?  can you post `spark.read.parquet("some_directory").printSchema()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reading specify the **`schema`** as schema adds null values for non existing columns then convert to **`DataSet`**.

**`Example:`**

```
case class SomeCaseClass(attr_1: String, attr_2: Long, attr_3: String)

val sch=Seq[SomeCaseClass]().toDF.schema

spark.read.schema(SomeCaseClass).parquet("some_directory").as[SomeCaseClass]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this seems to be extracting the schema from your class and passing it to Spark as a parameter when calling the csv read.
Frankly, did not find this documented anywhere so not sure why this should work and how one is expected to know about this.
This pattern was explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45415778/4776587) as a solution to a similar issue.

```
def readCsv[T <: Product : TypeTag](file: String, spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] = {
    val encoder = Encoders.product[T]
    spark
        .read
        .option("header", "true")
        .schema(encoder.schema)
        .csv(file)
        .as[T](encoder)
}
```